# Internal compiler error in condition with bool property

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-xe5

lately I have been faced with a strange problem that a simple source did not  want to compile. I was looking for solutions (and cause) in many sites but without good effects (except bugs reports but I have not found there direct cause ).

Below I present simple code to reproduce that situation:

```
struct Foo {
  Foo() : m_x( true ) {}
  __property bool x = { read=m_x };

  private:
    bool m_x;
};

template<typename T>
struct TMyPointer {
  T * m_ptr;
  TMyPointer( T * ptr ) : m_ptr( ptr ) {}
  ~TMyPointer()
  {
    delete m_ptr;
  }

  T * operator->() const
  {
    return Get();
  }

  T * Get() const
  {
    if( m_ptr == NULL )
      ; // some error handling

    return m_ptr;
  }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  TMyPointer<Foo> bar( new Foo );

  if( bar->x && 1 == 1 ) ; // Failed
  if( 1 == 1 && bar->x ) ; // OK
  if( !!bar->x && 1 == 1 ) ; // OK
  if( bar->x == true && 1 == 1 ) ; // OK
  if( (bar->x) && 1 == 1 ) ; // OK

  return 0;
}
```

Compiler has failed to compile first condition inside main function. What stranger compilation of other equivalent conditions is finished successfully.

That's behavior I have only during release compilation. To reproduce I have used Embarcadero® C++Builder® XE5 Version 19.0.13476.4176

> Error message: [bcc32 Fatal Error] File1.cpp(43): F1004 Internal
>   compiler error at 0x14470090 with base 0x14410000

Anybody knows what is the problematic in above example? Maybe usage templates with properties mechanism is the cause?

Comment: An ICE should always be reported to the compiler supplier/vendor.  It means that the compiler recognizes that something went wrong.  By definition, it shouldn't have happened; the vendor is likely to want to fix it, especially if you have a small clean reproduction (an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) is the term used at Stack Overflow). They'll be most anxious to fix it in the current version; as your compiler version is more ancient, they'll be less keen on fixing it unless it also causes problems in the current version.

Comment: Just curious - why are you are re-inventing `std::auto_ptr`/`std::unique_ptr` instead of using them as-is?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Yes, you have got right but it does not depend on me. I work in greater team which maintains rather old application. Many mechanisms has been written years ago and  worked through years without any problems. Lately colleague from team wrote new functionality causes the compilation problem. While debugging I reached the conclusion that condition is the cause.

Remember please that above code is only simple example which reproduce thats situation. Of course my colleagues know that smart pointers exist but I think it does not matter for that topic :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case is simple solution it seems to be problematic condition inside Get method. When I change

```
if( m_ptr == NULL )
```

to equivalent form

```
if( !m_ptr )
```

everything compile without errors.

I am writing about it here becouse I would like to share my insights - it can be helpfully for somebody.

Comment: As others have said, you should report this to Embarcadero, so they can be made aware of this bug. If not there is not much possibilities of them fixing it. In any case, they most certainly wont fix anything on XE5 (nor 6, nor 7) so it's good to have a workaround, as you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

recently I got similar ICE (once my source code grows in size) and your solution seemingly helped for a while but not really as after some minor changes in code ICE resurfaced again. Based on the behavior of mine problem:

- IDE: BDS2006 Turbo C++ explorer (its version of BCB between BCB6 and RAD)
- Huge win32 project (several MBytes of code involving USB,OpenGL,CAD/CAM)
- Each part of code is tested for years and compilable separably problem occurs once they together and code grows too big
- Project compiles fine at first run but after that any recompile fails

The temporary workaround was to close IDE, delete all obj,tds,exe,... files restart IDE and compile again.

I assumed compiler and or IDE leaks or overwrites some parts of itself corrupting its functionality. As the problem persist after IDE restart without deleting temp files I assumed it has something to do with debug info stored in them.

So I played with `Project->Options->Debugging settings` and **turning off** this:

- **Inline function expansion (-vi)**

Helped (not even IDE restart or temp file removal was needed).

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough reputation to upvote or comment someone else's posts, but I have recently found the same solution as in @Spektre reply.

Disabling **Inline function expansion** fixed our multiple-year problems with completely unrelated internal compiler errors on random projects. We only experienced them on **MSBUILD** scripts in **Release** config.

I found this out by going over all the compiler options in **Release** config that were different from **Debug** config and changed them one-by-one to match **Debug** config through **msbuild** parameters for the entire solution/projectgroup. And eventually it started to build without any errors when I've disabled **Inline function expansion** option.

- These problems happened and I confirmed the fix on C++ Builder XE5;
- This kept on resurfacing at random for as long as I can remember (Borland C++ 2006 and later)
- The older developers used to try and revert latest commits until it started compiling again... Which is a pain in the behind.

Anyone looking for solution to pass a parameter to an **MSBUILD** command (for all targets in the script) add this line to the **msbuild.exe** call:

```
msbuild.exe Targets.xml /p:BCC_InlineFunctionExpansion=false /t:Build
```